# Tornado and ZeroMQ

Tags: python, tornado, pyzmq

I've been trying to follow the code in [Eventloops and PyZMQ](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/eventloop.html), specifically the following code:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import ZMQPoller

loop = IOLoop(ZMQPoller())
```

I'm trying this and I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACaron\Desktop\develop\spectator\site\lib\site-packages\tornado\testing.py", line 170, in setUp
    self.io_loop = self.get_new_ioloop()
  File "C:\Users\ACaron\Desktop\develop\spectator\tests\test_agent.py", line 16, in get_new_ioloop
    return IOLoop(ZMQPoller())
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Looking at the [documentation for Tornado's I/O loop](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html), I can see that indeed, the `IOLoop` class constructor does not accept arguments.

I'm guessing there are some API changes in Tornado.  I'm using PyZMQ 14.3.0 and Tornado 3.2.1.  Is this a bad combination of package versions?  If not, what's the new way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like outdated documentation - Tornado's IOLoop has never taken any documented arguments, although ZMQ used to use an undocumented argument in earlier versions of Tornado.  I think using the install() function should work in current versions of Tornado.  I'm not sure how to use the ZMQ IOLoop in a way that is AsyncTestCase-friendly.  I think there's a subclass of IOLoop somewhere in the ZMQ codebase that you can instantiate directly.

Comment: Thanks, I just got a working example with the `AsyncTestCase`.  It seems you need to override the test case's `get_new_ioloop()` method and return a `zmq.eventloop.ioloop.ZMQIOLoop` instance.

Comment: By the way, I just sent in a pull request to PyZMQ to fix this part of the documentation :-)